# Explainability of a model

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, statistical-significance, model

I am trying to answer this question:

[image]

This question is actually based on the Mackay plot here: the simpler the model, the more it places its mass towards the left

[image]

However I'm not quite able to arrive at an answer. I'm leaning towards (a) thinking about this way: the earth's surface can be described as a sphere or as a flat-earth "reasonably well", but obviously one of them is wrong.

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how to solve this?

Comment: Both descriptions of the Earth are wrong.  Within any small area (less than a few hundred kilometers across) the flat-earth description can be better. What do you suppose the "right" assumption for a description of part the Earth's surface might be? As you think about an answer, bear in mind that modern cartographers use literally hundreds of different descriptions, including descriptions that change continually with time (by design).

Comment: You may get more attention to your question if you type the text in the linked picture, and remove the link. In the meantime, a famous quote says: "All models are wrong, but some are useful"...it should help you think through the problem.